# What is the difference between regular "for" statement and range-based "for" statement in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto

So, what is the difference between these two statement:

```
for(auto i : VectorName){}


for(auto i = VectorName.begin(); i != VectorName.end(); i++){}
```

For example, I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 vector<char> vec = {'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d','!'};
 for(auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++) // This loop has error
     {        
     cout << i << endl;
}
 for(auto k : vec) //This loop has no problem
 {
     cout << k << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I am confused because in this example in this [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/auto-cpp?view=msvc-160):

```
// cl /EHsc /nologo /W4
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque<double> dqDoubleData(10, 0.1);

    for (auto iter = dqDoubleData.begin(); iter != dqDoubleData.end(); ++iter)
    { /* ... */ }

    // prefer range-for loops with the following information in mind
    // (this applies to any range-for with auto, not just deque)

    for (auto elem : dqDoubleData) // COPIES elements, not much better than the previous examples
    { /* ... */ }

    for (auto& elem : dqDoubleData) // observes and/or modifies elements IN-PLACE
    { /* ... */ }

    for (const auto& elem : dqDoubleData) // observes elements IN-PLACE
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

They noted that the range for statement is not better than the regular one.

Comment: is your question which is better or why doesn't your code work? please stick to one question per post

Comment: "not much better than the previous examples" I.e. it is some improvement, but still not as good as it can be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in your case is, that the first version with iterators, well, uses iterators (that's why `cout << i << endl;` is not working), and the second version (the range-based for loop) gives you either a copy, a reference, or const reference.

### So this:

```
for(auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i << endl; // should be *i
}
```

uses iterators (`vec.begin()` gives you an iterator to the first element).

### Whereas this:

```
for(auto i : vec)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

uses copies of elements in your vector.

### While this:

```
for(auto& i : vec)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

uses references to your vector elements.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
{
    //cout << i << endl; // should be cout << *i << endl;
    auto& k = *i;
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

`i` is an iterator, you have to deference it to retrieve the value to be nearly equivalent to second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Regular for loop uses an explicit loop variable, in your examples an iterator `i` or `iter` (many times it is just an integer). To access elements in a vector for example, you need to use the loop variable to extract the elements from the vector.

Range-based for loops automatically gives you the elements inside the container you loop over, so there is no need to extract the elements inside the loop, you can immediately use `k`/`elem`.

About the comment you mention: that specific range-based style with no references is usually bad for performance (if the copy is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

> So, what is the difference between these two statement:
>
> ```
> for(auto i : VectorName){}
>
>
> for(auto i = VectorName.begin(); i != VectorName.end(); i++){}
> ```

The first one will iterate through *every* item in the collection; `i` is a copy of the item.

The second one gives you more *control* over the range; `i` is an iterator, dereference to access item.